# .htaccess URLRewrite rule - regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm in need of a rewrite rule for a site of mine.

I have the following type of URLS:

```
http://bag-saver.com/store/category/yellow-bags/?brand=TedBaker
```

But I would like that to read:

```
http://bag-saver.com/store/category/yellow-bags-by-tedbaker/
```

This is what I think should work:

```
RewriteRule ^-(.*) ?brand=$1
```

(it doesn't)

But then in addition, the `?brand` parameter could actually appear as an `&parameter` - e.g. `?word=clutch&brand=TedBaker`.

To summarise - I would like the brand parameter to be made into the final part of the static URL, preceded by the word 'by'. I would like this to work regardless of where the brand parameter appears in the URL string.

Here is the current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And here are all the URLs this needs to apply to:

```
http://bag-saver.com/store/category/black-bags/?brand=Jaeger
http://bag-saver.com/store/category/black-bags/?brand=Jaeger&word=Cross%20Body
http://bag-saver.com/store/category/black-bags/?word=Cross+Body&brand=Jaeger
```

Above need to be converted to /store/category/black-bags-by-jaeger/ or /store/category/black-bags-by-jaeger/?word=Cross%20Body (for 2nd and 3rd options).

I also have this:
http://bag-saver.com/store/search/?brand=Jaeger which needs to be converted to /store/search/bags-by-jaeger/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : (if you can gives us all the variants of the url it would be better)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-by-([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$3?brand=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work - I tried putting it before and after RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L].

Comment: htacces does not convert your old **normal** urls into nice ones (you do that manualy by editing the links in your files), htacces rewrites requests with new nice urls into old ugly urls (without notifing the user that there was a redirection), that's what the htaccess do (and that is what the rule I wrote to you do, it converts `/store/category/black-bags-by-jaeger/` to `/store/category/black-bags/?brand=Jaeger`

Comment: Ah, well that explains it. Thanks very much.